# Third party Facebook login to authenticate not working

Tags: facebook, authentication, error-handling, github-third-party-apps

I am not a frequent user of Facebook but the current issue I am faced with is logging into my game which is connected using Facebook. I generally face no problems getting into the game without any further questions on `authentication`, but today I found that I was disconnected from the game, unlinked to any sources. So I tried to log into my account by authenticating it through Facebook. (I am still logged in on Facebook, have no suspensions or bans) When the game forwards me to the Facebook app, this constant message pops up at the top saying:

> App not active: This app is not accessible right now and the app developer is aware of the issue. You will be able to log in when the app is reactivated.

I am very confused, and this poses as a major concern for me as I cannot lose this account. I went to the settings of Facebook as well under Apps and Websites, and the game remains active showing me when I added it and if I would like to remove/unlink it, which I will not be doing. I don’t know how to use Facebook for developers either, if that is something that is involved. I have made an account though.

I already tried searching up solutions for hours, `youtube videos`, `restarting` and on/offs

Comment: Are we talking about an app that you are an admin or developer of; or just an app that you have been _using_, provided by someone else? (If you are saying you only created a developer account now, I suppose it can only be the latter, but please clarify.)

Comment: Yes, this is an app that I just use. I am not the developer of this app.

Comment: Then there isn't anything anyone here can do for you. This issue needs to be locked at and solved by the app developer.